# Ver página de localhost levantada sobre intellijIDEA y Angular de desde otro ordenador dentro de la red

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

Cuando hago ping a esa ip desde otro ordenador, si hay flujo de paquetes pero cuando intento acceder poniendo (IP):4200/#/pages/usuarios no me carga nada.
Saben de algún método para hacer esto posible?

Comment: Al parecer no es posible accedes desde fuera. Puedes ejecutar otra instancia del servidor con `ng serve -host 0.0.0.0`. Puedes ver mas info aqui https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1475#issuecomment-235986121 Al final lo importante saber es, quieres hacer pruebas con diferentes equipos? Si estás utilizando chrome puedes crear cuentas diferentes en el navegador para mantener datos para cada usuario. Otra alternativa es usar dos navegadores diferentes (Yo lo uso para ver si todo anda bien) Seria  bueno que expusieras que es lo que buscas al conectarte desde otra maquina.

Comment: Si esto es con el objetivo de que los analistas funcionales puedan consultar las pantallas y realicen su documentación para que no le quiten tiempo al developer solicitandole los pantallazos

Comment: Puedes hacer un compilado de la versión que tienes y montarla en un servidor apache dentro de tu máquina. Asi ellos podrían entrar a través de ip.